# ARIMA prediction model saved into file and used later on for forecasting

Tags: python, file, object, model, save

I want to save the ARIMA model object I created for future use - how to do it in the most efficient form? Right now, I create the model, say arima_mod, and use `arima_mod.forecast()`. How can I save this model as text and revoke it later on? I am pretty sure that it can be done with `pickle` but I don't understand how to call it properly for this case...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK... one way to do it is by using `arima_mod.save('file')` and then creating an arbitrary `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMAResultsWrapper object` as follows:

```
model = sm.tsa.ARIMA([0,1,2,3], order=(0, 0, 0))  
results_= model.fit()
```

and rewriting the "place-holder" model with the real one upon call

```
results_.load('file')
```

If anyone has a better solution, would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a very late answer, but...)

I don't think you need to create the arbitrary results wrapper object.  Just use the class method `ARIMAResults.load()`([doc](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.load.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.load)).

```
# earlier:
some_model.save('file')

# now:
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMAResults
results_ = ARIMAResults.load('file')
```